# Quadrado Misterioso

Tags: c, algoritmo

> Os números inteiros posicionados em um quadrado NxN tal que todas as linhas e diagonal principal têm a mesma soma.
>
> Por exemplo, o quadrado abaixo
>
> ```
> 2 7 11
> 9 5 6
> 4 3 13
> ```
>
> é um quadrado misterioso de soma 20, pois todas as linhas (2+7+11 = 20, 9+5+6 = 20 e 4+3+13 = 20) e diagonal principal (2 + 5 + 13 = 20) têm a mesma soma (20).
>
> Escreva um programa que, dado um quadrado, determine se ele é misterioso ou não e qual a soma dele (caso seja mágico).
>
> **Entrada**
>
> A primeira linha contém um inteiro N. As N linhas seguintes contêm N inteiros cada, separados por exatamente um espaço em branco.
>
> **Saída**
>
> Seu programa deve imprimir, na saída padrão, uma única linha com um inteiro representando a soma do quadrado mágico ou -1 caso o quadrado não seja mágico.

PS: não posso usar vetor, só posso usar estruturas de repetição.

> **EXEMPLO 1**
>
> **ENTRADA:**
>
> ```
> 3
> 2 7 11
> 9 5 6
> 4 3 13
> ```
>
> SAÍDA:
>
> ```
> 20
> ```

PS: A minha saída foi:

> -1

Segue o meu código:

```c
int main()
{
    int n, i, j, elem;
    int , soma_linhas = 0, soma_dp = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);


    //leitura dos elementos
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &elem);
            //somatorio de cada linha
            aux += i;
            soma_linhas = aux;
        }
    }

    //somatorio da diagonal principal 
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(i == j){
                aux += i + j;
                soma_dp = aux;
            }
        }   
    }

    if(soma_linhas == soma_dp)
        printf("%d", soma_linhas);//se for quadrado misterioso tanto faz mostra a linhas ou da diagonal 
    else
        printf("-1");
    return 0;
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Seu exemplo de entrada não se trata de um quadrado mágico. O somatório de nenhuma das colunas é `20`. A saída esperada seria `-1`.

Comment: Esse que é a questão. É um quadrado misterioso não um mágico. Por isso que deve ser só a soma das linhas e da diagonal principal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vejamos esses laços:

```
//leitura dos elementos
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        scanf("%d", &elem);
        //somatorio de cada linha
        aux += i;
        soma_linhas = aux;
    }
}
```

Independente do que aconteça, ao final `soma_linhas` e `aux` terão o mesmo valor. Qual será o valor de `aux`. Para um quadrado de 3x3, será 0 na primeira iteração, 1 na segunda (+1) e 3 na terceira (+2). No entanto, não era isso que ele deveria fazer! Não há sentido somar os valores de `i` e desconsiderar os valores de `elem`. Você deveria é verificar os valores de `elem`.

No entanto, mesmo se você usar `aux += elem;`, ainda vai estar errado, pois isso vai acabar somando todos os valores, e não os valores de cada linha separadamente.

O que você tem que fazer é mudar esse laço para que ele vá somando os valores de cada linha e a partir da segunda linha, compare com o valor da linha anterior.

Note que você não está armazendando os valores lidos em lugar nenhum, a variável `elem` só irá guardar o último valor. Por causa disso, o seu laço para verificar a diagonal principal também não vai funcionar, pois você só está somando valores fixos 0, 1 e 2 e ignorando completamente o conteúdo da matriz.

Sem armazenar a matriz inteira, fica bem difícil verificar se todas as linhas e a diagonal principal têm os mesmos valores. Mas como você não pode armazenar os valores em vetores, você faz o seguinte:

- Use uma variável (vamos chamar de `ok`) para indicar se as somas das linhas e da diagonal principal coincidem. Inicialize ela com 1.
- Leia a primeira linha, somando todos os itens (vamos chamar isso de `a`). Armazene o primeiro elemento em uma variável auxiliar (`b`).
- Use um `for` para ler as demais linhas, somando os elementos de cada linha em uma outra variável `c`. O elemento da coluna principal você soma também à variável `b`. Ao final de cada linha, confira se `a == c` e mude `ok` para 0 se não for. Não se esqueça de voltar `c` para 0 antes de começar a linha seguinte.
- Ao terminar a última linha, confira se `a == b` e mude `ok` para 0 se não for.
- No fim, basta verificar a variável `ok`.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int elem, a = 0, b = 0, ok = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &elem);
            if (i == j) b += elem;
            if (i == 0) a += elem;
            c += elem;
        }
        if (a != c) ok = 0;
    }
    if (a != b) ok = 0;

    if (ok) {
        printf("Quadrado misterioso com soma %d.", a);
    } else {
        printf("Não é um quadrado misterioso.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no ideone:

- [**Para um quadrado misterioso.**](https://ideone.com/PgfBpE)
- [**Para um quadrado não misterioso.**](https://ideone.com/NGqefP)

Comment: Fiquei curioso sobre uma implementação prática da solução **sem usar vetores**.

Comment: @Lacobus Resposta editada.

Comment: @VitorStafusa: As colunas do quadrado não estão sendo verificadas! `2 + 9 + 4 == 15`, `7 + 5 + 3 == 15` e `11 + 16 + 13 = 40`. (O quadrado da pergunta não se trata de um quadrado mágico!)

Comment: @Lacobus Isso é o esperado. Leia o enunciado, ele não fala nada sobre as colunas. O quadrado misterioso diz respeito apenas às linhas e à diagonal principal. Talvez você esteja pensando no [quadrado mágico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrado_m%C3%A1gico) que esse sim tem que ter a soma das linhas, colunas e ambas as diagonais iguais. Todo quadrado misterioso é mágico, mas o contrário não necessariamente é verdadeiro.

Comment: @Lacobus Até dá para verificar a diagonal secundária sem usar vetor, mas para as colunas, acredito que o uso de um vetor de acumuladores seja inevitável. No entanto, como isso é para verificar se o quadrado é misterioso ao invés de mágico, não preciso desse vetor pois não preciso das colunas.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sobre as colunas, precisa de `o(N)` de memória extra. Independente se tiver de validar as linhas. Inclusive isso me deu uma ideia de questão estilo code-golf aqui xD

Answer (score 3):

Você não menciona na pergunta nada sobre o somatório das colunas, segundo a [`Wikipedia`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrado_m%C3%A1gico) a definição de um `Quadrado Mágico` é:

> **Quadrado Mágico** é uma tabela quadrada igual a intersecção de números
>   em que a soma de cada coluna, de cada linha e das duas diagonais são
>   iguais.
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue uma solução testada e comentada para verificar se um dado quadrado misterioso é mágico ou não, veja só:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int eh_magico( int ** quad, int n )
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int d1 = 0, d2 = 0;

    /* Somatorio das diagonais */
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        d1 += quad[i][i];
        d2 += quad[n - i - 1][i];
    }

    /* Verifica se diagonais sao iguais */
    if( d1 != d2  )
        return -1;

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        /* Somatorio linha e coluna */
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            x += quad[i][j];
            y += quad[j][i];
        }

        /* Verifica linha e coluna */
        if( x != d1 || y != d1 )
            return -1;
    }

    /* Eh magico! */
    return d1;
}


int main( void )
{
    int lin, col, dim;
    int ** quadrado_misterioso;

    /* Le dimensoes */
    scanf( "%d", &dim );

    /* Aloca memoria para n linhas */
    quadrado_misterioso = malloc( dim * sizeof(int*) );

    /* Para cada linha */
    for( lin = 0; lin < dim; lin++ )
    {
        /* Aloca memoria para n colunas da linha atual */
        quadrado_misterioso[lin] = malloc( dim * sizeof(int) );

        /* Para cada coluna da linha */
        for( col = 0; col < dim; col++ )
            scanf( "%d", &quadrado_misterioso[lin][col] );
    }

    /* Verifica se eh um quadrado magico */
    printf("%d\n", eh_magico( quadrado_misterioso, dim ) );

    /* Libera memoria ocupada pelo quadrado */
    for( lin = 0; lin < dim; lin++ )
        free(quadrado_misterioso[lin]);
    free(quadrado_misterioso);

    return 0;
}
```

Teste (`n = 3`):

```
3
4   9   2
3   5   7
8   1   6
15
```

Teste (`n = 4`):

```
4
2   16  13  3
11  5   8   10
7   9   12  6
14  4   1   15
34
```

Teste (`n = 5`):

```
5
1   23  16  4   21
15  14  7   18  11
24  17  13  9   2
20  8   19  12  6
5   3   10  22  25
65
```

Teste (`n = 3`):

```
3
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
-1
```

Teste (`n = 3`):

```
3
2   7   11
9   5   6
4   3   13
-1
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/vDywIw)

Comment: É porque essa questão não está se importando com os valores das colunas. Nem da diagonal secundária. Há na verdade um erro de redação na questão, ela deveria ser resolvida com memória constante, independente de N